Drag and drop issue in Angular
I could not trigger ondrop function.
Here is my code  - can anyone help with this?
<div class="canvas-container">
    <canvas #canvasElement></canvas>
    <div class="drop-zone" cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)">
      <p >Drag and drop content here</p>
      <img  [src]="droppedItem" class="dropped-image">
    </div>
    <div class="drag-container">
      <div cdkDrag class="draggable-item">
        <p>Drag me</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

 onDrop(event: CdkDragDrop<any>) {
   const canvas = this.canvasElement.nativeElement;
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x = event.pointerPosition.x - rect.left;
    const y = event.pointerPosition.y - rect.top;

    // Example: Draw the dropped content on the canvas
    this.ctx.fillStyle = 'blue'; 
    this.ctx.fillRect(x - 25, y - 25, 50, 50); // Adjust size and position as needed
}

I need to drag and drop image over the image and combine it into one image
